# Object Move arrows no longer aligned to grid?

Tags: objects, interface

I'm working on a project where I suddenly realized that the object Move arrows are no longer aligned to the grid, rather they're aligned to my viewing position in the 3D view. I must have done something to make this happen; how do I change the Move arrows back to be aligned to the grid? Thanks. Windows 10, Blender 3.0.0

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are currently using *view transform orientation*. Because of this, the gizmo will always be oriented toward your view.

From [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/editors/3dview/controls/orientation.html?#transform-orientations) on view transform orientation:

> **View**
>
> Align the transformation axes to the window of the 3D Viewport:
>
> - Y: Up/Down
> - X: Left/Right
> - Z: Towards/Away from the screen

You may change it back to global in the header as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Timaroberts! :)